# What is the difference between capturing and non-capturing Pattern?

Tags: java, regex

In the `Pattern` class it says there are two types of regex: *capturing* and *non-capturing*, but I don't understand the difference.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#special

How are they different? When do I have to use each one? Any examples?

Comment: Back references allow you to refer to a captured.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider a pattern where you need to check for a variety of things in a single position, e.g a bunch of different two character patterns. Normally you use the `|` alternation operator:

```
/(ab|cd|ef)/
```

which requires use of `()` brackets as well. But those brackets also act as a capturing group. Maybe you really don't want to capture those char sequences, just check for their presence, which is where the non-capturing groups come into play:

```
/(?:ab|cd|ef)/
```

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question, but I struggle how this explains anything. To me, it reads like "You use capturing regexes when you want to capture...". If knowing what *capturing* groups *are* is not the problem, then this is like asking: "When do I use an iPod and when do I use a pen"?

Answer (score 3):

You may want to *group* expressions independently of them *capturing* something. For instance:

```
abc(foo|bar)def
```

If you want to match either "abdfoodef" or "abcbardef", but no other variations, this is the simplest expression. You had to use `()` to group two expressions to use the `|`. But this also means that `(foo|bar)` is the first capturing group.

If you don't want or need the capture, write it as a *non-capturing group*:

```
abc(?:foo|bar)def
```

Answer (score 1):

Capturing/non-capturing does not refer to the entire regex, but to groups, i.e. *parenthesized expressions*.

Do you want to

- use **backreferences**?
- retrieve a **specific portion** of the entire match? (or multiple)

If *yes*, then you will want *capturing* groups.

If *not*, then you are using parentheses for *precedence control* and can make the group non-capturing.

Answer (score 1):

A capturing group allow you to reuse part of the regex match. You can reuse it inside the regular expression, or afterwards for example in a replace statement :

consider this text : 1a2b3cdef7g9h
and this regex : ([0-9]*)([a-z]*)
There's two capturing groups, the first one which capture the sequences of digits, the second one for capturing sequences of letters.

So you can use a replaceAll statement to keep digits using the first capturing group ($1) or to keep letters with the second one ($2).

```
    // next line outputs : 12379
    System.out.println("1a2b3cdef7g9h".replaceAll("([0-9]*)([a-z]*)", "$1"));

    // next line outputs : abcdefgh
    System.out.println("1a2b3cdef7g9h".replaceAll("([0-9]*)([a-z]*)", "$2"));
```

But when you use a non capturing group (for example by adding ?: it does not capture, and it's sometimes usefull. So for example :

```
    // next line outputs : abcdefgh
    //  ([a-z]*) becomes the first capturing group because (?:[0-9]*) is a non-capturing group
    System.out.println("1a2b3cdef7g9h".replaceAll("(?:[0-9]*)([a-z]*)", "$1"));
```

Try it on http://gskinner.com/RegExr 
at the bottom of the screen you can see where are your capturing groups

See : http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html

Answer (score 1):

Just thought I should mention that you can also create named capture groups like so:

```
(?<telephone>(?:\(\d{2}\)\s\d{4}\s\d{4}))
```

Which would match a telephone number like `(02) 9502 5697`

You could then use it as a backreference like so:

```
"s/(?<telephone>(?:\(\d{2}\)\s\d{4}\s\d{4}))/\k<telephone>/g"
```

Which would just replace the match with itself... but you can be creative with it.

Hope this helps.